# How to find Point of A5 size to print C#?

Tags: c#, printing

I create an application to get data from Excel and print a bill from its data.

I printed successfully but I don't know how to calculate Point(x, y) to puts my data in A6 pages.

And I put class `Express()` in `foreach loop`, but I want to set 2 A6 size in 1 A5 pages and continues `foreach loop`.

Like this image:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
private void Print(int id, PrintDialog dialogPop)
{
    stt = id;
    printDialog = dialogPop;
    ExcelConnect excelLoad = new ExcelConnect(sFileName);
    dtExcel = excelLoad.ExcelLoad("Sheet1");
    foreach(DataRow dt in dtExcel.Rows)
    {
        stt = Int32.Parse(dt[0].ToString());
        ten = dt[1].ToString();
        Express();
    }
}

private void Express()
{
    PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();

    printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printDialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
    printDoc.PrinterSettings.Copies = printDialog.PrinterSettings.Copies;
    printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(firstPage);
    printDoc.Print();
}

private void firstPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    // Logo
    Image img = INGIAYGUIHANG.Properties.Resources.logo;
    Bitmap logo = new Bitmap(img);
    logo.SetResolution(198, 80);

    // Header & Address
    e.Graphics.DrawString("abc", new Font("Courier", 25), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new Point(454, 25));
}
```